# Can't locate CDN in bootstrap themes folder while creating a drupal website

Tags: drupal, cdn, drupal-themes

I am new to drupal and a bit stuck. I am about to make a bootstrap subtheme. I have downloaded the drupal 8 folder from drupal's website and that is what I'm using. I have tried to follow tutorials on creating subthemes, all of them mentioning the CDN folder inside themes/bootstrap/starterkits directory. However, in my case, I can't locate it anywhere. Is there a way of manually downloading and pasting the folder from another source? Any help will be appreciated!

---

My *themes/bootstrap/starterkits*

[image: contents]

Answer (score 0):

In order to extend your theme, you must create a fresh theme and then, in your theme.info.yml extend the base theme

```
core: 8.x
type: theme
base theme: bootstrap //or your base theme
```

To create a new theme from scratch, this article will help you

https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/how-to-create-a-basic-drupal-8-theme

Answer (score 0):

The tutorials you are following is out of date. According to this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/3049485), all starterkits have been replaced with a single generic starterkit, which is the folder `THEMENAME` you see.

Now, you can follow the updated tutorial [here](https://www.webwash.net/getting-started-bootstrap-drupal-8/#create-sub-theme).